# what's relationship between Three.js and directx?

Tags: 3d, three.js

Three.js is a js library for 3D ,  the directx and openGL are two main libraries for Rendering (basic tech for computer graphic ),is the Three.js based on directx or openGL?

Comment: Perhaps spending some time on [the Wikipedia article for three.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three.js) would help illuminate matters.

Answer (score 4):

It is "based on" neither.

Three.js is a higher-level rendering library that calls into one of multiple backend renderers. It can draw to a Canvas element, an SVG image, or WebGL. And WebGL is based on OpenGL ES 2.0, which is (in theory) a subset of some version of desktop OpenGL. So it's several steps removed from desktop GL.

That being said, many WebGL implementations in browsers actually use Direct3D backends on Windows. The WebGL calls are simply translated into D3D9 equivalents.

So what's the "relationship" here? There isn't a formal one, and any relationship is based entirely on how WebGL is implemented in browsers, not anything that is *explicitly* controlled by Three.js.